# css selectors for AS3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, css-selectors

I'm coding some ActionScript 3 app that needs to request some HTML page and analyse it. I am fetching it and parsing as XML - so far so good. Now, I'll have to check for many various things in it and I have no idea how to do that without too much coding and fixed things.

Are there any AS3 methods or libraries, that would allow for quick searching in XML, for example by class/id attribute, preferably using css selectors - i.e. `#id .className1 > .className2`, etc?

The idea is that I want more maintainability than optimizations, as there's a chance it will involve many changes in the future.

So, are there any libraries or methods that could make querying xhtml easier? Or maybe something open source with css selectors that I could base my code on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) is already built in... and CSS selectors will work on HTML text, if you're going to display it in a text field.

Comment: I'm not sure you got the css part right: I don't want to display any HTML, or use css for formatting, I only meant "css selectors" as patterns to search for specific tags in xhtml. Anyway, E4X seems like a good direction, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I got the CSS part. I felt like it was additional info that might help others when looking for answers in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, wrote an AS3 library myself for it: http://code.google.com/p/actionscript-xml-css-selectors/ , it uses E4X. It is LGPL'd, sharing if anyone is used to css selectors as much as I do.